# Javascript: Countdown by animation.width()

Tags: javascript, css, animation, countdown

I am currently trying to make a visual countdown for my user for when the animation is finished. My current attempt looks somewhat like this:

```
function setClassAndFire(){
    timer = setInterval(function () {
            t--;
            $(this).attr('class', 'timerAnimation');
            countdownTimer();
            if (t === 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                timer = undefined;
                funcForCall();
            }
    }, 1000);  
}

function countdownTimer(){
    var timerCurrentWidth = $('.timerAnimation').width(),
        timerMaxWidth = $("#awardQueueText").width(),
        pxPerSecond = timerMaxWidth / 60,
        currentCountdown = timerCurrentWidth / pxPerSecond;
        currentCountdown = Math.round(currentCountdown);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "<span style='white-space : nowrap;'>Animation ends in:</br></span>"+
            "<span style='white-space : nowrap;'>" + currentCountdown + " sec.</span>";
}
```

Important to know is that the animation only displays the time until we may be able to send an API call. So the animation will be re-engaged if we have something in queue.

So as you can see my current attempt works, but is some-what cluncky:

> The countdown sometimes fails to subtract a second and "fixes"
>   that with a 2 seconds subtract in the next attempt.

This is probably caused by the **Math.round()** for **currentCountdown**, but is there a work around for that? I mean I have the max possible width of the animation object and can seperate it from the current width.

Is there a way to bring it to work? We need to relate the timer to the animation to achive desired behavior. So when the animation count hits 25, I want that the displayed number is 25 as well!

Answer (score 0):

You got this problem because you got the number from the width andh the width can't have decimals (or better, they can be but they are gonna be truncated sometimes). 
So my suggestion is to use a differente variable for the number you will show and the width of the DOM element.
It seems to me that the variable `t` is what I am talking about, so just try to use it.

```
 function setClassAndFire(){
        timer = setInterval(function () {
                t--; //What is t? 
                $(this).attr('class', 'timerAnimation');
                countdownTimer(t);
                if (t === 0) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    timer = undefined;
                    funcForCall();
                }
        }, 1000);  
    }

function countdownTimer(t){
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "<span style='white-space : nowrap;'>Animation ends in:</br></span>"+
            "<span style='white-space : nowrap;'>" + t+ " sec.</span>";
}
```

Comment: _t--; //What is t?_
t is used as an escape value in the later code:

`if (t === 0) {
     clearInterval();
     etc.
}`

Comment: it was in your code, i was asking to you that and I assumed you know what is it because you use it to clear(or not) the interval.

Comment: sorry, I accidentaly pressed TAB+Enter which resulted in an unfinished answer.

Comment: Ok, but what it rappresent? Which value start from?

Comment: it represents the number 60 which is a variable value the user can alter if he wants to. 60 seconds for one minute. Interestingly, when i tried your solution with 't', I am receiving "undefined" as value when I am submiting it to the next function (countdownTimer(t))

Comment: Have you added the variable as argument of the function when you declare it too?

Comment: yes, it is defined in the function's parenthese; both in call and definition

Comment: Are you sure t is defined inside the interval handler?

Comment: okay, my bad, I am working with a new development environment, VS Code, and didnt notice the first function wasn't saved. Even though it is available it will be subtracted every second and will only reset on 'timer === 0', meaning it will become smaller and smaller for every call we make. So after call one, number will be 59 and after call 2 it will be 58 while the animation gets reset every time.

Comment: I've found a solution for the display of the current time, but that does not help with the exact problem. The reason for trying to do it with the animation is to be able to pause the animation and restart it on-point without a wrong countdown.